# How to speed up Word2Vec's initial vocabulary scan for massive data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, gensim, word2vec

I now have a massive data corpus dataset, it has about 11 billion sentences, each sentence has about 10 words, divided into more than 12,000 files ending with .txt.gz. I wish to Skip--Gram it with Gensim's Word2Vec.I'm using Gensim's multi-file streaming method PathLineSentences to read the data.

```
sentences=PathLineSentences('path')
w2vModel=Word2Vec(sentences,
              vector_size=128, 
              window=5, 
              min_count=2,
              workers=24,
              epochs=200,
              sg=1,
              hs=1,
              batch_words=100000,
              compute_loss=True）
```

But I found a problem that the vocabulary scan phase before training is very slow (because it can only run in a single thread?), the following is a screenshot of the TOP command information：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L143Y.png)
it has been running like the above for almost 12 hours. Can the vocabulary scan at this stage be multithreaded or is there any other way to speed it up? Thank you all.
Here is my callback:

```
class callback(CallbackAny2Vec):
def __init__(self,path_prefix):
    self.epoch = 0
    self.path_prefix = path_prefix
    self.loss_to_be_subed = 0
    self.start_time = datetime.now()
    self.end_time = datetime.now()

def on_epoch_begin(self,model):
    self.start_time = datetime.now()
    print('Epoch {} start'.format(self.epoch))

def on_epoch_end(self, model):
    self.end_time = datetime.now()
    loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()/100000
    loss_now = loss - self.loss_to_be_subed
    self.loss_to_be_subed = loss
    print('Loss after epoch {}: {}'.format(self.epoch, loss_now))
    print("Epoch {} end".format(self.epoch))
    output_path = '{}_epoch_{}.model'.format(self.path_prefix, self.epoch)
    model.save(output_path)
    print('duration of epoch {} is {}\n'.format(self.epoch,self.end_time-self.start_time))
    self.epoch += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial vocabulary-scan is unfortunately single-threaded: it must read all data once, tallying up all words, to determine which rare words will be ignored, and rank all other words in frequency order.

You can have more control over the process if you refrain from passing the `sentences` corpus to the initial constructor. Instead, leave it off then call the later steps `.build_vocab()` & `.train()` yourself. (The `.build_vocab()` step will be the long single-threaded step.) Then, you have the option of saving the model after the `.build_vocab()` has completed. (Potentially, then, you could re-load it, tinker with some settings, and run other training sessions without requiring a full repeated scan.)

Also, if you're just starting out, I'd recommend doing initial trials with a smaller dataset - perhaps just some subsampled 1/10th or 1/20th of your whole corpus – so that you can get your process working, & optimized somewhat, before attempting the full training.

Separately, regarding your implied setup:

- Using a value as low as `min_count=2` is usually a bad idea with `Word2Vec` & related algorithms. The model can only achieve useful vectors for words with a variety of multiple usages - so the class's default of `min_count=5` is a good *minimum* value, and when using a larger corpus (like yours) it makes more sense to increase this floor than lower it. (While increasing `min_count` won't speed the vocabulary-survey, it will speed training & typically *improves* the quality of the remaining words' vectors, because without the 'noise' of rare words, other words' training goes better.)
- Even if your machine has 24 CPU cores, in the traditional (corpus-iterator) mode, `Word2Vec` training throughput usually maxes out with somewhere in the range of 6-12 workers (largely due to Python GIL bottlenecks). Higher values slow things down. (Unfortunately, the best value can only be found via trial & error – starting training & observing the logged rate over a few minutes – and the optimal number of workers will change with other settings like `window` or `negative`.)
- With such a large dataset, an `epochs=200` is overkill (and likely to take a very long time). With a large dataset, you're more likely to be able to use less than the default `epochs=5` than you'll need to use more.
- By setting `hs=1` without also setting `negative=0`, you've enabled hierarchical-softmax training while leaving the default negative-sampling active. That's likely to at least double your training time, & make your model much larger, for no benefit. With a large dataset, it's odd to consider `hs=0` mode at all – it becomes less performant with larger models. (You should probably just avoid touching the `hs` value unless you're sure you need to.)
- Similarly, it's unclear why you'd want to change the defaults for `batch_words` & `compute_loss`. (The loss-tallying will slow things down, but also doesn't work very well yet - so it's rare to need.) In general, your setup changes a lot of things best left untouched, unless/until you're sure you can measure the net effects of the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.The reason why I set epochs=200 and enable compute_loss is that I set the following callback(I added the callback code to the question above). I calculate the loss of each epoch and hope to find the model with the lowest loss among the 200 epochs as the final trained model. My linux development machine actually has 96 cores, also Does that mean the best number of workers is 24-48? After reading your answer I know that I need to keep the hs value at the default value.

Comment: The final loss is a bad measure of model quality. A model with a higher loss might have better word-vectors for a particular purpose. A model with a 0 loss is likely worthless, because it's almost certainly overfit on insufficient data. (Getting every training word-prediction exactly right will mean zero for general applicability to other diverse texts.) So, I don't recommend that. (Further, if any online source recommended that approach: it's a bad source! Don't trust it!)

Comment: There's no chance you'll need 200 epochs with your 100B word (500GB+) dataset, and you are unlikely to want to wait that long for results. I'm pretty sure I once saw a reliable report that the famous Google-release `GoogleNews` word-vectors, in 2012 based on ~100B words of news articles, only used 3 epochs.

Comment: In the traditional corpus-iterator mode – what you're using via the `PathLineSentences` helper – I've usually observed top training-step throughput using 6-12 workers, no matter how many cores are available (be they 16, 64, 96, or 1024). It's a weakness of the Python GIL & current multithreading design. But again, the actual number will depend on your setup/parameters/etc. The alternative `corpus_file` mode can train effectively keeping more worker threads busy, but it requires your corpus be a single giant pre-tokenized file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Your answer will save me a lot of training time.But I still have a question, that is, should I remove the repeated sentences (the type and order of the words in the sentences are exactly the same), in my 11 billion sentences, there are about 20% of the repeated sentences, I have checked a lot of information, it seems Everyone got rid of it? I don't know what effect it will have on the model after removing it. what do you think?

Comment: Hard to say. Repeated information generally less valuable – you can't truly simulate a diverse 10x larger corpus by just repeating some smaller corpus 10 times – but repeated texts/phrases do have effect of providing extra weight (training reinforcement) for those contexts... which might help, or hurt, the final results. Only trying it both ways & comparing results on your true end tasks can tell for sure. (In meantime, I'd suggest running trials with much smaller subsets of the data 1st, to get a generally idea of what works - only testing other variations when you've got a working baseline.)